# Google sheets script to email when form response received

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, html-email

I have a sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NcCZ5Y7YrL63e2i6osQC28MOG3_Mq4fLPUANFrxxYNE/edit#gid=725463476 with multiple forms feeding it. I need a script that when a new response is received it will pull the data from a different sheet and email it. I will need a script that I can modify for each different form response. So if possible have a sheet to watch and sheet where the data is pulled form called out in the script so I can just change the sheet name in the script for each different one. I have about 7 or 8 of these in my real sheet. I will also need some html probably in it? Maybe it can pull the colors/size/bold ect from the sheet? If not I will need to know how to add font size/color/bold and even trickier if it cant pull this from the sheet I will need conditional colors based on the words pass and fail. Green for pass and red for fail. I will be in and out of the sheet fell free to leave notes on the sheet ect. It's just a sample so type away. Hope to chat in the sheet with someone who can help me out!

Thank you!
Stephen

Comment: Just looking for a clarification:  Are you looking to use this to learn to write the script yourself or are you hoping someone will do this for you?

Comment: A little bit of both. I'm good with formulas but not with script. I'm looking for something that I'll be able to maintain and edit enough for all 7 or 8 of my form responses.

Comment: Take a look at this [Simple Mail Merge Tutorial](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/mail_merge) and consider what you might need to re-write to accomplish your needs.  Then ask specific questions in new posts.

Comment: I have read through a few of those and I still struggle to even know where to start. I have even tried taking a few simple java classes ect. It's just something that I struggle with grasping. Was hoping to get quite a bit of direction with this?

Comment: So i will need someone to pretty much write it for me and explain a little bit of it so I can modify it for my other sheets and forms. Thanks

Comment: Are all of your questions required to provide an answer?

Comment: Sorry, Cooper. No not all will always have answer. Some will be blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Sending Emails from Google Forms Submit

This is a menu that you can use to create your trigger it only allows you to create one trigger at a time.

```
function coopermenu() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Cooper Menu')
  .addItem('Create Trigger', 'createFormSubmitTrigger')
  .addToUi();
}
```

This will setup your trigger

```
function createFormSubmitTrigger(funcname) {
  var funcname=funcname||'form1Submit';
  if(!isTrigger(funcname)) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger(funcname).forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActive()).onFormSubmit().create();
  }
}
```

And this is the function that the trigger runs along with your upgrade requests:

```
function form1Submit(e) {
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  Logger.log('Sheet: %s',e.range.getSheet().getName());
  var sheetname=e.range.getSheet().getName();
  switch(sheetname) {
    case 'Form Responses 1':
      if(e.values && e.values[1] && e.values[2]) {
        var html='<table>';
        html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td colspan="2">%s</td></tr>','To:',getGlobal('form1Email'));
        html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>','&nbsp;','&nbsp;','&nbsp;' );//empty line
        html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td colspan="2">%s</td></tr>','Subject:',getGlobal('form1Subject'));
        html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>','&nbsp;','&nbsp;','&nbsp;' );//empty line
        html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td><strong>%s</strong></td></tr>','&nbsp;','TimeStamp:',e.values[0]);
        html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td><strong>%s</strong></td></tr>','&nbsp;','Location:',e.values[1]);
        html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td><strong>%s</strong></td></tr>','&nbsp;','Name:',e.values[2]);
        html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>','&nbsp;',RoGpf(e.values[3]),RoG(e.values[3]));
        html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>','&nbsp;',RoGpf(e.values[4]),RoG(e.values[4]));
        html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>','&nbsp;',RoGpf(e.values[5]),RoG(e.values[5]));
        html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>','&nbsp;',RoGpf(e.values[6]),RoG(e.values[6]));
        html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>','&nbsp;',RoGpf(e.values[7]),RoG(e.values[7]));
        html+='</table>';
        Logger.log(html);
        GmailApp.sendEmail(getGlobal('form1Email'), getGlobal('form1Subject'), '', {htmlBody:html});
      }
      break;
    case 'Form Responses 2':  
      if(e.values && e.values[1] && e.values[2]) {
        var html='<table>';
        html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td colspan="2">%s</td></tr>','To:',getGlobal('form2Email'));
        html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>','&nbsp;','&nbsp;','&nbsp;' );//empty line
        html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td colspan="2">%s</td></tr>','Subject:',getGlobal('form2Subject'));
        html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>','&nbsp;','&nbsp;','&nbsp;' );//empty line
        html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td><strong>%s</strong></td></tr>','&nbsp;','TimeStamp:',e.values[1]);
        html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td><strong>%s</strong></td></tr>','&nbsp;','Location:',e.values[0]);
        html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td><strong>%s</strong></td></tr>','&nbsp;','Name:',e.values[2]);
        html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>','&nbsp;',RoGpf(e.values[3]),RoG(e.values[3]));
        html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>','&nbsp;',RoGpf(e.values[5]),RoG(e.values[5]));
        html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>','&nbsp;',RoGpf(e.values[6]),RoG(e.values[6]));
        html+='</table>';
        Logger.log(html);
        GmailApp.sendEmail(getGlobal('form2Email'), getGlobal('form2Subject'), '', {htmlBody:html});
      }
      break;
  }   
}

function RoG(s) {
  if(s) {
    if(s=='Pass') {
      return '<span style="color:#00ff00;font-weight:bold">Pass</span';
    }else if(s=='Fail') {
      return '<span style="color:#ff0000;font-weight:bold">Fail</span>';
    }
  }
  return s;
}

function RoGpf(s) {
  if(s) {
    if(s=='Pass') {
      return '<span style="color:#00ff00;font-weight:bold">Pass/Fail</span';
    }else if(s=='Fail') {
      return '<span style="color:#ff0000;font-weight:bold">Pass/Fail</span>';
    }
  }
  return s;
}
```

These are some utilities that I used:

triggers.gs:

```
//Filename: triggers.gs
function deleteTrigger(triggerName){
  var triggers=ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  for (var i=0;i<triggers.length;i++){
    if (triggerName==triggers[i].getHandlerFunction()){
      ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
    }
  }
}

function isTrigger(funcName){
  var r=false;
  if(funcName){
    var allTriggers=ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
    for(var i=0;i<allTriggers.length;i++){
      if(funcName==allTriggers[i].getHandlerFunction()){
        r=true;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return r;
}

function deleteAllTriggers(){
  var triggers=ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  for (var i=0;i<triggers.length; i++){
    ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
  }
}

function showMeProjectTriggers(){
  var html='';
  var br='<br />';
  var triggers=ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  for(var i=0;i<triggers.length;i++){
    var name=triggers[i].getHandlerFunction();
    html+=br + 'triggers[' + i + '] = ' + name;
  }
  html+=br + '<input type="button" value="Close" onClick="google.script.host.close();" />';
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html).setWidth(800).setHeight(450);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, 'Project Handler Functions');
}
```

globals.gs

```
function getGlobals(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Globals');
  var rg=sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow(),2);
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var g={};
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++){
    g[vA[i][0]]=vA[i][1];
  }
  return g;
}

function setGlobals(dfltObj){
  var dfltH=Object.keys(dfltObj).length;
  if(dfltObj){
    var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Globals');
    var rg=sh.getRange(1,1,dfltH,2);
    var vA=rg.getValues();
    for(var i=0;i<dfltH;i++){
      vA[i][1]=dfltObj[vA[i][0]];
    }
    rg.setValues(vA);
  }
}

function getGlobal(name){
  return getGlobals()[name];
}

function setGlobal(name,value){
  var curObj=getGlobals();
  if(!curObj.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
    var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Globals');
    sh.appendRow([name,value])
  }else{
    curObj[name]=value;
    setGlobals(curObj);
  }
}

function cleanGlobals() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Globals');
  if(sh.getLastColumn()>2) {
    sh.getRange(1,3,sh.getLastRow(),sh.getLastColumn()-2).clearContent();
  }
  var rg=sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow(),2);
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    if(!vA[i][0] || !vA[i][1]) {
      var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Globals Sheet Requires Maintenance...Do it know.' + ' Check Row ' + Number(i + 1));
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, 'Global Maintenance Required');
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

- [Trigger Builder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/trigger-builder)
- [Form Event Object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit)

**Instructions**

1. Create globals.gs and paste globals script.
2. Create triggers.gs and paste triggers scripts.
3. Create cooper.gs and paste in the other scripts. I did this because other people were getting into code and they just deleted my scripts and over wrote theirs.  Not very kind in my mind.
4. Create a Globals Sheet. A1='form1Subject', A2='form1Email', B1='Your Subject', and B2='Your email'.
5. The go into the script editor and run coopermenu() and this will give your a permissions dialog.  You need to authorize inorder to run the script.  It figures out all of the scopes for you.
6. Then go to the new menu and press create trigger.  It will allow you to create only one at a time.
7. Go to the live form and fill one out
8. Read your email it will look something like this image below.
9. Since we have been having problems with spurious formSubmits I used the follow logic to prevent them `if(e.values && e.values[1] && e.values[2]) {` this means that your Name and Location question must be filled in in order to receive an email.

[image]

I made the spacing changes you requested and here's what the emails look like now.

[image]

Comment: Thank you big time to Cooper! You put in much time and effort to help me get this figured out just how I need it. Effort is much appreciated!

Comment: @BadFish523 I was wrong it is possible to determine which form was submitted by look at the event obj and using `e.range.getSheet().getName()` to determine which sheet the information was sent to.  So I think I can add that to the answer.

Comment: @BadFish523 I update the answer to include the capability keeping all of your Form Responses in the same Spreadsheet.  My 'Form Responses 2' is not the same as yours so you will have to modify it for your needs.  I got a couple questions out of order and had to rearrange the indices but I think you'll find the code fairly flexible.

Comment: Don't forget to add the Form2 parameters in your globals table.

Comment: with the possibility of these coming in very rapidly with multiple users I have decided it is probably best to just split them up and importrange the data into my single dashboard sheet. This way I can build the one sheet then make copies and link each form to it's own. Tested it this morning on one of my live sheets and it is working great!

Comment: I think that’s a good decision but if you find that the performance is adequate you can try this way I’ll go ahead and put the other answer up as well. Have a great day

Comment: Hey Cooper, another quick question. Currently the table has a space between the question and answer like this       Timestamp:                3/3/3 what would be the easiest way to remove that space? so like this    Timestamp: 3/3/3? I like having the space at the beginning or indent and I just kind of want to try this as a test. I tried removing a few things but being a table it seems to want to either remove all the nbsp from the whole row or none at all. I was hoping it would be simple but Ive tried several things with no luck? Any quick and easy solutions for this?

Comment: Guess the space didnt show up in my example but you will notice that there is a gap between the question and the answer. I would like to try and get the answer closer to the question. Dont need to put a ton of work into this just hoping for something simple.

Comment: Can you post your code as it is right now...just remove any unique like id's and personal stuff.

Comment: I guess I dont know how to post the code on here. If I try to post it as a comment its too long

Comment: It's nearly the same as the code in the cooper.gs for the Form Responses 1 Table.

Comment: @BadFish523 Edits Complete.  They are in the above code.

Comment: I will have to wait till Monday to test it out but it looks great! Looks like you used the colspan to make some if the cells stretch out and the strong to bring the others together? I will play with it Monday and let you know. Thanks again!

Comment: Just wanted to give an update, Cooper that worked great! A+ again sir!

Comment: Cooper here is the original post I'm referencing in my other post about the structure of the table.