# Send form response details to user that completed the form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have to migrate a Microsoft Excel 2010 file to Google Sheets. This file as a userform that allows a user to reply to a few questions. Those answers then goes to the excel sheet and pass by a various number of manipulations before giving back the results to the user.

I created a Google Forms and I migrated my Excel sheets to Google Sheets.On completion of the form, GForms write the information in GSheets. But then I'm stuck to bring back the results to the user.

On completion of the form, GForms write the information in GSheets, but I don't know how to bring back the results to the user that completed the form.It can be by mail, from a new GSheets, directly in GForms or else.

Comment: From the linked Spreadsheet you could use [Form Submit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit) Event Trigger. e.values has all of the answers in one array. You can use [GmailApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app) to send the email.

Comment: There are a couple of outstanding answers on this subject: [Google sheets script to email when form response received](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55716897/1330560) (by @Cooper, very detailed. more complicated than you need?); [Send a Google Forms response to specific email address based on form response](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/132665/196152) (step-by-step, though it includes a logic statement that you don't need); or [Send a google form result to an email](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/129695/196152) (a more simple example).