# How can I restructure HTML table in google app script?

Tags: html, css, email, google-apps-script, html-table

I have a google sheet with a script behind it that generates an email. The Body of the email is an HTML table. This all works good except for how the table is structured in the email. Due to the length of the link in the last line the second column get pushed over and then there is a large space between the text and the returned value. Is there anyway to modify the table structure to keep column 2 next to column 1? Maybe there is an alignment option or something to allow the link to overflow? Here is the table HTML.

```js
   

function form1Submit(e) {
      if(e.values && e.values[1] && e.values[2]) {
        var html='<table>';
        html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td><strong>%s</strong></td><td>%s</td></tr>','&nbsp;','Safety Findings Comment:',e.values[7]);
        html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td colspan ="2">%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>','&nbsp;','https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQj3j6QgrCyvULYo1IeE3q9L9Gzvz2tVvNI8650nhl-L0cQwyx93tRIeuXPxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/pubhtml#','&nbsp;' );
        html+='</table>';
    Logger.log(html);
    GmailApp.sendEmail(getGlobal('form1Email'), getGlobal('form1Subject'), '', {htmlBody:html});
  }
}
```

Here is the updated script that worked. I used both the formatting of the table and then the formatting of two of the columns.

```js
function form1Submit(e) {
  if(e.values && e.values[1] && e.values[2]) {
    var url='https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQj3j6QgrCyvULYo1IeE3q9L9Gzvz2tVvNI8650nhl-L0cQwyx93tRIeuXPxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/pubhtml#';
    var html='<style>td,th{padding:overflow-wrap: break-word;}table{table-layout:fixed;width:100%;}</style><table>';
    html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td style="width:35%;" colspan ="2"><font size="4" color="red"><b>%s</b></font></td><td style="width:65%;">%s</td></tr>','&nbsp;','**** DO NOT REPLY TO THIS EMAIL ****','&nbsp;' );
    html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td style="width:35%;">%s</td><td style="width:65%;">%s</td></tr>','&nbsp;','&nbsp;','&nbsp;' );//empty line
    html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td style="width:35%;">%s</td><td style="width:65%;">%s</td></tr>','&nbsp;','&nbsp;','&nbsp;' );//empty line
    html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td style="width:35%;" colspan ="2">%s</td><td style="width:65%;">%s</td></tr>','&nbsp;','Please review findings','&nbsp;' );
    html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td style="width:35%;" colspan ="2"><font size="5"><b>%s</b></font></td><td style="width:65%;">%s</td></tr>','&nbsp;','VISUAL WELDING AUDIT','&nbsp;' );
    html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td style="width:35%;"><strong>%s</strong></td><td style="width:65%;">%s</td></tr>','&nbsp;','Date and Time of Audit:',e.values[0]);
    html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td style="width:35%;"><strong>%s</strong></td><td style="width:65%;">%s</td></tr>','&nbsp;','Auditor:',e.values[1]); 
    html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td style="width:35%;"><strong>%s</strong></td><td style="width:65%;">%s</td></tr>','&nbsp;','Line/Location Audited:',e.values[2]);
    html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td style="width:35%;"><strong>%s</strong></td><td style="width:65%;">%s</td></tr>','&nbsp;','Area Responsible:',e.values[3]);
    html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td style="width:35%;">%s</td><td style="width:65%;">%s</td></tr>','&nbsp;',RoGpf(e.values[4]),RoG(e.values[4]));
    html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td style="width:35%;"><strong>%s</strong></td><td style="width:65%;">%s</td></tr>','&nbsp;','Person Notified:',e.values[9]);
    html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td style="width:35%;"><strong>%s</strong></td><td style="width:65%;">%s</td></tr>','&nbsp;','Disposition:',e.values[5]);
    html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td style="width:35%;"><strong>%s</strong></td><td style="width:65%;">%s</td></tr>','&nbsp;','Discontinuity Found:',e.values[6]);
    html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td style="width:35%;"><strong>%s</strong></td><td style="width:65%;">%s</td></tr>','&nbsp;','Safety Findings Comment:',e.values[7]);
    html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td style="width:35%;"><strong>%s</strong></td><td style="width:65%;">%s</td></tr>','&nbsp;','Additonal Comments:',e.values[8]);
    html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td style="width:35%;">%s</td><td style="width:65%;">%s</td></tr>','&nbsp;','&nbsp;','&nbsp;' );//empty line
    html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td style="width:35%;">%s</td><td style="width:65%;">%s</td></tr>','&nbsp;','&nbsp;','&nbsp;' );//empty line
    html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td style="width:35%;" colspan ="2">%s</td><td style="width:65%;">%s</td></tr>','&nbsp;','Link to Dashboard:','&nbsp;' );
    html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td style="width:35%;" colspan ="2">%s</td><td style="width:65%;">%s</td></tr>','&nbsp;',url,'&nbsp;' );
    html+='</table>';
Logger.log(html);
GmailApp.sendEmail(getGlobal('form1Email'), getGlobal('form1Subject'), '', {htmlBody:html});
  }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) and [mcve]. [Google Apps Script Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script).

Comment: Remove the undefined variables and/or provides us a [mcve]

Comment: Cooper, you helped me write it to begin but I since added the link and it throws off the alignment. Here is the original post here but the sheet and form are not longer current. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55711352/google-sheets-script-to-email-when-form-response-received

Comment: Here is the new sheet and form. Both are examples and you can feel free to submit responses and edit. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/188ClpgSV3r3lWHkenwacDMV97jesJBoN7ABrH2LvDd4/edit#gid=0 and https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSda1HLwehW_an4FxXJsoBuSxX1J-BExQOdvRx4jMQ7kz2ETEQ/viewform?usp=sf_link

Comment: I have added an image of the problem and desired result in the sheet.

Comment: Please provide [mcve] posted in your question. I don’t follow links to spreadsheets.

Comment: Cooper I read that link twice. The code I provided should be the minimal code needed I think. I'm not real good with this stuff. You wrote every script in this project. The code above is 100% written by you other than the last 4 lines that I added.

Comment: I added the two blank lines and the Link to Dashboard line and the line with the actual link. I don't know how to post a picture here. I see nothing to embed a picture.

Comment: I requested a minimum reproducible example which means a function that I can run to reproduce the problem. Your example is not a function and it has undefined variable or functions unit. So I cannot run it to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Cooper I commented on the original post here where you wrote the code. I have tried adding the script including all functions from each function in the sheet but it says it's too long. I tried using ctrl+K that just opens my address bar in my browser. I tried indenting and fences. I can't figure it out. I help out on several forums myself so I know the importance of having the right information but I guess even after reading the links I still don't understand. This is kind of frustrating not being able to provide you the information you need.

Comment: You don’t have to provide the exact code all you have to do is provide a minimal complete example that produces the same problem so that I can fix it.

Comment: Ok well Ill try this. Ill post it in two comments. Here is the first part.

Comment: function form1Submit(e) {
      if(e.values && e.values[1] && e.values[2]) {
        var html='<table>';
        html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td><strong>%s</strong></td><td>%s</td></tr>','&nbsp;','Safety Findings Comment:',e.values[7]);

Comment: html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td colspan ="2">%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>','&nbsp;','https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQj3j6QgrCyvULYo1IeE3q9L9Gzvz2tVvNI8650nhl-L0cQwyx93tRIeuXPxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/pubhtml#','&nbsp;' );
        html+='</table>';
    Logger.log(html);
    GmailApp.sendEmail(getGlobal('form1Email'), getGlobal('form1Subject'), '', {htmlBody:html});
  }
}

Comment: You need to post this code in your question.

Comment: Ahh, ok I have updated the code in the question. See if I got it right now?

Comment: No still not what you need?

Comment: What does the data in your linked sheet look like?  An image would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm preparing to answer your question but here's your code:

```
function form1Submit(e) {
      if(e.values && e.values[1] && e.values[2]) {
        var html='<table>';
        html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td><strong>%s</strong></td><td>%s</td></tr>','&nbsp;','Safety Findings Comment:',e.values[7]);
        html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td colspan ="2">%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>','&nbsp;','https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQj3j6QgrCyvULYo1IeE3q9L9Gzvz2tVvNI8650nhl-L0cQwyx93tRIeuXPxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/pubhtml#','&nbsp;' );
        html+='</table>';
    Logger.log(html);
    GmailApp.sendEmail(getGlobal('form1Email'), getGlobal('form1Subject'), '', {htmlBody:html});
  }
}
```

And I don't know what e.values looks like so I don't really know how to test your code because I have undefined variables.  So while your example may be minimal it's not reproducible.

So I made up my own input.  I also  display the result on a dialog because I didn't want to send emails.  The css is in the html string. Presumably, you can make this work in the email.

```
function form1Submit(e) {
      if(e.values && e.values[1] && e.values[2]) {
        var url='https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQj3j6QgrCyvULYo1IeE3q9L9Gzvz2tVvNI8650nhl-L0cQwyx93tRIeuXPxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/pubhtml#';
        var html='<style>td,th{padding:2px;border:1px solid black;overflow-wrap: break-word;}table{table-layout:fixed;width:100%;}</style><table>';
        html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td><strong>Safety Findings</strong></td><td>%s</td></tr>',e.values[7]);
        html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>%s</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>',url);
        html+='</table>';
    Logger.log(html);
    //GmailApp.sendEmail('email', 'Subjecet', '', {htmlBody:html});
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html), "Test");    

  }
}

function testAbove() {
  var e={values:['one','two','three','four','five','six','seven','eight','nine']};
  form1Submit(e) 
}
```

Here's what the dialog looks like:

[image]

You can also do something like this:

```
function form1Submit(e) {
      if(e.values && e.values[1] && e.values[2]) {
        var url='https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQj3j6QgrCyvULYo1IeE3q9L9Gzvz2tVvNI8650nhl-L0cQwyx93tRIeuXPxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/pubhtml#';
        var html='<style>td,th{padding:2px;border:1px solid black;overflow-wrap: break-word;}table{table-layout:fixed;width:100%;}</style><table>';
        html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td style="width:10%;">&nbsp;</td><td style="width:60%;"><strong>Safety Findings</strong></td><td style="width:30%;">%s</td></tr>',e.values[7]);
        html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>%s</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>',url);
        html+='</table>';
    Logger.log(html);
    //GmailApp.sendEmail('email', 'Subjecet', '', {htmlBody:html});
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html), "Test");    

  }
}
```

[image]

You can adjust this by adjusting the width of each column separately.

Comment: Cooper, thank you for sticking with me and getting me a working solution! I put my updated script in my original question. Hopefully I updated everything correctly. Thanks you again @Cooper!